# Convergence of a series with Weierstrass criterion

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I want to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$

converges on $X=[0, 1]$

My approach was

$$\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \le \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \le \log2$$

so

$$\Vert f_n\Vert_{\infty,X} \le \log2 \lt \infty$$

and we know that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$$

so

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to \log1=0$$

and lets consider $S_i$ the partial sum from $n=1$ to $i$

we have $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall n,m \gt N$ and $(m \gt n)$

$$\Vert S_m - S_n\Vert_{\infty,X} \lt \epsilon$$

So the serie is Cauchy and we can conclude with Weierstrass criterion that it is uniformly convergent on $X$.

I am just wondering if I made a mistake since I just begun in analysis and I'm never sure.

Comment: You claimed (and wote formally) that $(S_n)$ is Cauchy but you did not prove it. $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to0$ does not suffice. Besides, your upper bound $\log2$ is useless.

Comment: What you can say is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)<
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\infty.$

Comment: Ok thank you! I didn't want to use this bound cause if I want to prove it on $X=[0,+\infty)$ it doesn't work. And does the fact that it tends to $0$ does not suffice is cause there exists series that tends to zero but are still divergent?

Comment: On $[0,+\infty)$ it works the same: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac a{n^2}\right)< a\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\infty.$ And yes, e.g. the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).